# Not able to push multiple elements inside the stack in java collection framework . When i print the stack only one elements is there

Tags: java

Not able to add multiple elements inside the stack in java collection framework. whenever i print the stack then also the stack is showing the currently added element  inside the stack. I am trying to add multiple elements inside the stack so that i can perform all stack related operations.

```
import java.util.*;

public class stackexp1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Stack<Integer> numberss = new Stack<Integer>();
            System.out.println("\n.........Operations on stack ...........");
            System.out.println("1 >> Push >> 1 ");
            System.out.println("2 >> Pop >> 2 ");
            System.out.println("3 >> Display >> 3 \n");
            int choice, num;
            System.out.print("Enter your choice >> ");
            Scanner sdc = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = sdc.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("Your  choice was push operation ......:)");
                    System.out.print("\nEnter a number to be pushed >> ");
                    Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
                    num = b.nextInt();
                    numberss.push(num);
                    System.out.println(numberss);
                }
                    break;
                case 2: {
                    if (numberss.size() >= 0) {
                        System.out.println("Your choice is pop operation ......:)");
                        System.out.println("The element from the stack >> " + numberss.pop());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\nStack is empty");
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 3: {
                    if (numberss.size() >= 0) {
                        System.out.println("Your choice is display Stack elements .....:)");
                        System.out.println("The elements inside the stack are >> " + numberss);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Stack is empty ....:)");
                    }
                }
                    break;
                default: {
                    System.out.println("No such choice is available ....:)");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ## Output .. >>

> [image: Output of the code >>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are creating a new stack on each iteration of the *while* loop.

Move the declaration and initialization of the stack outside the *while* loop. Also, you don't need more than one instance of a `Scanner`. You can move that outside the loop as well.

```
Stack<Integer> numbers = new Stack<>();
Scanner sdc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: System.out.print("Enter your choice >> ");
Scanner sdc = new Scanner(System.in);
choice = sdc.nextInt();
 this is for just the choice of the user it need to be keep inside bcz i am taking user choice after performing each stack operations

Comment: It doesn't have to be. Only `choice = sdc.nextInt();` should be inside the loop, you don't have to create a new Scanner object (`new Scanner(System.in)`) each time.

Comment: i will do the same changes thanks very much